# Can a cookiecutter pre_prompt.py hook access the value of the template's `output_dir`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, cookiecutter

I'm attempting to write a simple [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io) `pre_prompt.py` validation script that inspects the parent directory from which the template is being executed.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to determine the value of `output_dir` via Jinja.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

print(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))

print(f"{{ cookiecutter.output_dir}}")
```

The above simplistic `example_template/hooks/pre_prompt.py` script results in the following:

```
$ cookiecutter example_template

/tmp/cookiecuttera0gwfqwi
{ cookiecutter.output_dir}
```

This shows that the value of `os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` is the temporary directory created during template processing while my naïve attempt to access `{{ cookiecutter.output_dir}}` was not interpreted by Jinja in any meaningful way.